# Issue navigation bar color change in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am using sencha-touch 2.3 cupertino-classic ios theme.There is a problem for me to change color of navigation Bar. its by default color is apple default navigation bar.Please any body help me. I am new in sencha-touch.
Thanks.

Comment: Try SASS to apply theme..

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend you to try existing UI schemes. For the cupertino-classic theme they are: `light`, `dark`, `black` , `neutral` (look at _Toolbar.scss for cupertino-classic theme). For using them use the following config for your navigation view:

```
navigationBar: {
    ui: 'black'
}
```

If these default colors is not your case, then try add your own style. I think of two variants. The first more elegant is to add your custom UI. Because cupertino-classic theme hasn't all necessary mixins for doing this, you have to get them from the other (e.g. from default theme). You will need mixins as: `sencha-toolbar-ui`, `bevel-by-background`, `bevel-text`, `toolbar-button`. After that you can use example from the docs:

```
// SCSS
@include sencha-toolbar-ui('sub', #58710D, 'glossy');

// js
navigationBar: {
    ui: 'sub'
}
```

The second more straightforward is to write your custom style based upon existing UIs in _Toolbar.scss directly.